# SeckeychainItemref undeclared

Tags: iphone, twitter, oauth

When I am integrating `MGTwitterEngine` in my app, this error is coming:

```
"SeckeychainItemref" undeclared
```

Can anyone tell how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SeckeychainItemref is not available in the iOS SDK. 
As far as I know, its only used, for testing in the iPhone simulator. (if you found it in the code for a iOS app)

If it isn't for iOS, then you should add the Security framework and import Security/Security.h in your code.

Comment: I am not able to solve it .. Security/Security.h already imported in my OAToken_KeychainExtensions.h file but not works ..

Answer (score 4):

I had similar problem while building OAuthConsumer for iOS - I removed unwanted Mac specific key-chain files .h/.m and I can build it on iOS.